# jQuery toggle menu items and sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written code that works very well, but unfortunately it is not perfect functional. I will describe briefly the action:
When I click on '.navbar-nav li a' parent and '.sheets, .sheetsBg' get active class.
If I click again '.navbar-nav li a' is properly removed only for the menu item parent class.

code:

```
function manageSheetsToggle() {

var navMenuItem = '.navbar-nav li a';

$(navMenuItem).click(function (e) {
    if (!isTabletResolution() && !isPhoneResolution()) {
        {
            var sheetId = $(this).parent().data('target');

            if ($('.sheets, .sheetsBg').hasClass('active')) {
                $('.sheets, .sheetsBg').removeClass('active');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            $("#" + sheetId).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            $(".sheets, .sheetsBg").addClass("active");
        }
    } else {
        $(navMenuItem).click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                location.href = $(this).attr('href');
            }
        );
    }
});

$('.sheetsBg, .corpoBelt, .header').click(function () {
    $(".sheets, .sheetsBg").removeClass("active");
});
}
```

pls help.

Comment: can you give a fiddle ?? to identify the problem

Comment: hi, thx for answer. https://jsfiddle.net/kuzi/uq3o7qv1/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are luking for. I changed your code a little bit, but it works fine now. Try it and let me know

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var sheet, ln, cn = 0;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#toggleMenu").find("a").on("click", function (e) {
                ln = $(this);
                sheet = ln.parent().data('target');
                $("#" + sheet).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');
                $(".sheets").find("section").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).hasClass("active"))
                        cn++;
                });
                if (cn) {
                    $(".sheets").addClass('active');
                    cn = 0;
                } else
                    $(".sheets").removeClass('active');
            });
            $('.corpoBelt').click(function () {
                $(".sheets").removeClass("active");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: yes, its work now. Only added "if" for tablet and phone :) THX!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `siblings()` selector more easier

https://jsfiddle.net/2q50kj3a/1/

Comment: hi, thx, i'm use this as well but need toggling this with containers out. Look: https://jsfiddle.net/kuzi/uq3o7qv1/10/

Comment: @Tomasz what is the problem?